# How to know which element is tapped in ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, windows-phone-8.1

I've got a ListView with a DataTemplate like this, using MVVM pattern

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source}"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          commands:ItemsClickCommand.Command="{Binding ItemClickedCommand}">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding A}" />
                       <Button Content="{Binding B}" />
                   </StackPanel>
               </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

ItemsClickCommand is defined in this way

```
public static class ItemsClickCommand
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command", typeof(BindableCommand), typeof(ItemsClickCommand), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnCommandPropertyChanged));
    public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject d, BindableCommand value)
    {
        d.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }
    public static BindableCommand GetCommand(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (BindableCommand)d.GetValue(CommandProperty);
    }
    private static void OnCommandPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as ListViewBase;
        if (control != null)
            control.ItemClick += OnItemClick;
    }
    private static void OnItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = sender as ListViewBase;
        var command = GetCommand(control);
        if (command != null && command.CanExecute(e.OriginalSource))
            command.ExecuteWithMoreParameters(e.OriginalSource, e.ClickedItem);
    }
}
```

What I'm asking is how can I know if user tap on the TextBlock or Button.
I tried to handle ItemClickCommand event in this way in ViewModel to search controls in VisualTree (is this the best solution?), but the cast to DependencyObject doesn't work (returns always null)

```
public void ItemClicked(object originalSource, object clickedItem)
    {
        var source = originalSourceas DependencyObject;
        if (source == null)
            return;            
    }
```

Comment: You can put the command on the button inside DataTemplate

Comment: @Bells No, I can't. When I set the ItemsSource to ListView, the DataContext changed. So, if I put a command at Button, the command is searched into the class of element binded.
i.e.: if the collection binded as ItemsSource is of type ObservableCollection<T>, the Command assigned to the button is searched into T type

Comment: You could also get the selected item, before the click event,an item is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few solutions that come to mind

**Solution 1**

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="parent"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" 
    IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
    Margin="20">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding A}" />
                <Button 
                    Content="{Binding B}" 
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.BCommand, ElementName=parent}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Note how the ListView has the name set to "parent" with the attribute: `x:Name="parent"` and how the binding for the button's command uses that. Also note that the command will be provided with a parameter that is the reference to the data source for the element that was clicked.

The view model for this page will look like this:

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MySource> Source { get; private set; }

    public MvxCommand<MySource> BCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Source = new ObservableCollection<MySource>()
        {
            new MySource("e1", "b1"),
            new MySource("e2", "b2"),
            new MySource("e3", "b3"),
        };

        BCommand = new MvxCommand<MySource>(ExecuteBCommand);
    }

    private void ExecuteBCommand(MySource source)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ExecuteBCommand. Source: A={0}, B={1}", source.A, source.B);
    }
}
```

'MvxCommand' is just a particular implementation of ICommand. I used MvvMCross for my sample code but you don't have to do that - you can use whatever MvvM implementation you need.

This solution is appropriate if the responsibility to handle the command lies with the view model for the page that contains the list.

**Solution 2**

Handling the command in the view model for the page that contains the list may not always be appropriate. You may want to move that logic in code that is closer to the element that is being clicked. In that case, isolate the data template for the element in its own user control, create a view model class that corresponds to the logic behind that user control and implement the command in that view model. Here is how the code would look like:

The XAML for the ListView:

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" 
    IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
    Margin="20">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <uc:MyElement DataContext="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MySourceToMyElementViewModelConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The XAML for the user control representing one element:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source.A}" />
        <Button Content="{Binding Source.B}" Command="{Binding BCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The source code for MySourceToMyElementViewModelConverter:

```
public class MySourceToMyElementViewModelConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return new MyElementViewModel((MySource)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

The view model for the main page:

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MySource> Source { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Source = new ObservableCollection<MySource>()
        {
            new MySource("e1", "b1"),
            new MySource("e2", "b2"),
            new MySource("e3", "b3"),
        };
    }
}
```

The view model for the user control representing one element in the list:

```
public class MyElementViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public MySource Source { get; private set; }
    public MvxCommand BCommand { get; private set; }

    public MyElementViewModel(MySource source)
    {
        Source = source;
        BCommand = new MvxCommand(ExecuteBCommand);
    }

    private void ExecuteBCommand()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ExecuteBCommand. Source: A={0}, B={1}", Source.A, Source.B);
    }
}
```

**Solution 3**

Your sample assumes that the view model for the main page exposes a list of data model elements. Something like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<MySource> Source { get; private set; }
```

The view model for the main page could be changed so that it exposes a list of view model elements instead. Something like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyElementViewModel> ElementViewModelList { get; private set; }
```

Each element in `ElementViewModelList` would correspond to an element in `Source`. This solution can get slightly complex if the contents of `Source` changes at run time. The view model of the main page will need to observe `Source` and change `ElementViewModelList` accordingly. Going further don this path you may want to abstract the concept of a collection mapper (something similar with an ICollectionView) and provide some generic code for doing so.

For this solution, the XAML will look like this:

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementViewModelList}" 
    IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
    Margin="20">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding A}" />
                <Button Content="{Binding B}" Command="{Binding BCommand}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Notes for Solution 1, 2 and 3**

I see that your original sample associates a commanding not with the button inside of the element but with the entire element. That raises the question: what are you going to do with the inner button? Will you have a situation where the user can click either on the element or on the inner button? That may not be the best solution as far as UI/UX goes. Be mindful of that. Just as an exercise and in order to get closer to your original sample, here is what you can do if you want to associate commanding with the entire element.
Wrap your entire element in a button with a custom style. That style will modify the way a click is handled visually. The simplest form of that is to have the click not create any visual effect. This change applied to *Solution 1* (it can easily be applied to *Solution 2* and *Solution 3* as well) would look something like this:

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="parent"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" 
    IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
    Margin="20">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button 
                Command="{Binding DataContext.BCommand, ElementName=parent}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}" 
                Style="{StaticResource NoVisualEffectButtonStyle}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding A}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding B}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In this case you would have to write NoVisualEffectButtonStyle but that is a simple task. You would also need to decide what kind of commanding you want to associate with the inner button (otherwise why would you have an inner button). Or, more likely you could transform the inner button in something like a textbox.

**Solution 4**

Use Behaviors.

First, add a reference to "Behaviors SDK".[image: adding a reference to Behaviors SDK]. Then modify your XAML code:

```
...
xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
...

<Grid>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Margin="20">

        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction 
                    Command="{Binding BCommand}" 
                    InputConverter="{StaticResource ItemClickedToMySourceConverter}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding A}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding B}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

ItemClickedToMySourceConverter is just a normal value converter:

```
public class ItemClickedToMySourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (MySource)(((ItemClickEventArgs)value).ClickedItem);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

The view model will look like this:

```
public class Main4ViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MySource> Source { get; private set; }

    public MvxCommand<MySource> BCommand { get; private set; }

    public Main4ViewModel()
    {
        Source = new ObservableCollection<MySource>()
        {
            new MySource("e1", "b1"),
            new MySource("e2", "b2"),
            new MySource("e3", "b3"),
        };

        BCommand = new MvxCommand<MySource>(ExecuteBCommand);
    }

    private void ExecuteBCommand(MySource source)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ExecuteBCommand. Source: A={0}, B={1}", source.A, source.B);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, I used the first solution (probably the most simple) and it works. Thanks again